# scrollable views in drupal 6 is needed

Tags: views

I want to create a views with scrollable content. I've searched using google and found this : http://drupal.org/project/scrollable  but it is abandoned.

Is there anything similar to it ? I use Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from the "[View all releases](https://www.drupal.org/node/475882/release)" link (near the bottom of the module's project page). That page contains a link to [scrollable 6.x-1.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/node/475898).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Scrollable Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/scrollable_content) module, select the style as Scrollable Content. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides a scrolling functionality for your content. Scrollable Content will give you a nice content slider preview of your site's nodes, and provides some display options.
>
> The basic use is via blocks page, you'll find a block called "Scrollable Content" and if you want more control & you know how to use Views, you should use the Views style for Scrollable Content.

Hope it will match your requirement.